# H81M-HDS Intel Pentium G3220, not Posting, and no video

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, motherboard, bios, post

I am experiencing issues with a, H81M-HDS motherboard with an Intel Pentium G3220, when I press the power button, the fans spin for half a second, it turns off, does it again, and will then spin the fans, and the hard drive will make a single beep, no video output or power to any USB devices, like keyboard/mouse, what could be causing this? I have tried resetting every thing. Thinking on the possibility of a BIOS incompatibility issue, but do not know how to update it, with out it the PC posting.

EDIT: its the  PCH IC that is  getting moderately hot. Not the GPU

Comment: This motherboard doesn't have an on-board GPU, no modern motherboards do - it's integrated in the CPU. This CPU is supported since BIOS version 1.60, so old BIOS may be an issue. I don't think you'll be able to update it without a compatible CPU.

Comment: Oh, what is under that heatsink that is getting moderately hot? Yes, the bios chip has p1.60 written on it, so it should be fine? any thing I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Okay, turns out its the PCH, I am assuming the motherboard is dead, that should not be getting that hot, should it?